# How to Display MySQL Table from Dropdown List in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

This seems really simple but for the life of my I can't figure it out. Basically, I have the following HTML dropdown list:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<center>
<form method="post" action="myfile.php">
<table>
Select a table to display:
<select name = "list" size = "1">
<option value = "t1">TABLE 1</option>
<option value = "t2">TABLE 2</option>
<option value = "t3">TABLE 3</option>
<option value = "t4">TABLE 4</option>
<option value = "t5">TABLE 5</option>
</select>
<tr><colspan = "2">
<!- <p align = "center" ->
<input type="submit" value="Display Selected Table">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>
</html>
```

What I want to do is have the user select one of the 5 tables listed in the dropdown list and then click Display. Upon doing so, the system will display the full data from the corresponding table in the connected MySQL database.

My PHP file is practically a skeleton, but this is what I have at the moment:

```
<?php // myfile.php
    require_once 'login.php'; 
    $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database); 
    if ($conn->connect_error) die("Could not connect to database."); 

    // missing logic here
?>
```

I understand that the way it should be done is by employing a `SELECT * FROM TABLE` query, where `TABLE` is whatever the user selects from the dropdown list. I'm just not sure how to do that in my PHP. I've tried multiple times but none of my attempts really make sense considering the fact that I'm literally just starting to learn PHP.

**Clarification:**

I originally wanted to display the data in the form of a table, but I did not include that in my question because I already know how to do so. The issue was reading user input from a drop-down list, which I now understand.

Comment: Before diving into this you might want to have a look at w3 schools example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Just to familiarize yourself with using mysql and php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing logic is that your PHP script needs to get a way to access the user input (with regards with which table has been selected). You can actually keep both the HTML *and* the PHP on the same page, but only perform the query when you detect user input (i.e. by using the `GET` method on the `<form>` element, then listening in on the `$_GET[]` object).

Some implementation notes:

- Even when using MySQLi or PDO, prepared statements only work for `VALUES` parameter in the query. It is not possible to inject variables into prepared statements for the `FROM [tableName]` parameter.
- Related to the point above, you will have to *manually* create and maintain a whitelist of tables present in the selected database. Crosscheck the user input (of selected table of interest) against this known whitelist. If crosscheck fails, do not perform the query.

All this code can actually go to the same file, say `search.php`, and you simply redirect the form action back onto its own. However, without further information on how your database is structured, I am unable to suggest how you want to display your data.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<form method="get" action="search.php">
<table>
Select a table to display:
<select name = "list" size = "1">
<option value = "t1">TABLE 1</option>
<option value = "t2">TABLE 2</option>
<option value = "t3">TABLE 3</option>
<option value = "t4">TABLE 4</option>
<option value = "t5">TABLE 5</option>
</select>
<tr><colspan = "2">
<input type="submit" value="Display Selected Table">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['list']) && !empty($_GET['list']) {
        require_once('login.php');
        $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database); 
        if ($conn->connect_error) die("Could not connect to database."); 

        // Perform DB query using value of $_GET['list']
        // Have a manual white list of TABLES you want to accept
        $table = $_GET['list'];
        $tables = ['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5']; 
        if(in_array($table, $tables)) {
            // Perform query
            if(!$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE 1=1')) {
                die('Unable to perform query.');
            } else {
                // Loop through returned rows
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    // Do stuff here
                }

                // Free memory
                $result->free();
            }
        }

        // Close connection
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
</html>
```

p/s: You should really learn how to use CSS — stylistic HTML tags such as `<center>` has been deprecated quite some time ago.

Comment: I think he's asking more about how to actually retrieve the data and loop through it with php (using the mysqli functions).

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was asking. I tried looking into it but couldn't figure out how to make it work with a dropdown menu. Answer accepted.

Comment: @FieryPhoenix I'm glad I helped. I have updated the answer to explain why prepared statements, a championed feature of MySQLi and PDO (but not present in deprecated MySQL functions), are not relevant in your case. Also added some usage notes about whitelisting tables.